# Cant change the value, it stucks with 1 as default, why?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm new in react and doing testing, I need to do an unit test that should fail but is working, type should be empty when brandId is 2, but is the same as you run it with 1, that returns model. brandId with 2 is doing nothing

My testing file:

```
jest.mock("companycomponents/presentation", () => ({
  PresentationContext: () => ({
    brandProductSection: {
      brandIds: 2,
    },
  }),
}));

test("type should be 'model' when brandId is 2", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Results />);
  const typeDiv = getByTestId("article-card-type");
  expect(typeDiv).toHaveTextContent("model");
});
```

Parts of my code (not testing):

```
import {
  useDistributionContext,
} from "companycomponents/presentation";

export const Results: React.FC = () => {
  const [params, setParams] = useState<Record<string, string[]>>({});
  const [imageType, setImageType] = useState(model);
  const data = useResultPage(params);

  const context = useDistributionContext();
  const { brandIds} =
    context.brandProductSection;

  const handleChangeImageType = (data: ProductImageType) => {
    setImageType(data);
  };

const BRAND_ID = 1
const shouldHideSelector = !(
    data.length > 0 
    && (
        !brandIds 
        || (Array.isArray(brandIds) && !brandIds.includes(BRAND_ID))
    )
);

const typeString = shouldHideSelector ? `model` : "";


<div data-testid="article-card-type">{typeString}</div>
```

I dont know why it doesnt change the value in the tests

```
brandProductSection: {
      brandIds: 2,
    },
```

Comment: You use useDistributionContext in the component. Mokc that function itself to return what you want in the test.